# Is the order of receiving data guaranteed in Tizen message port?

Tags: c#, ipc, message, communication, tizen

In Tizen message port communication, Is the order of receiving data guaranteed?

If I were to ask more specific questions,

If I send a large amount of data several times, is the app that receives the data guaranteed to receive it in the order in which it was sent?

Or, I have to manage received data order when data receiving finished?

Comment: Would you let us know your application type - Native/Web/.NET ?

Answer (score 1):

The message port guarantees the order of receiving data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).